# Как получить владельца элемента?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть HTML:

```
<div id="my1">
    <input id="my2" value="123">
</div>
```

Получить элемент my2:

```
item = $("#my2");
```

Как получить владельца my1 через my2?

Answer (score 2):

Официальная документация по jQuery API — **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**,
Русская документация по jQuery API — **[.parent()](http://jquery-docs.ru/traversing/parent/)**

> Получает прямого «родителя» элемента.
> Если вызывается для набора элементов,
> то функция возвращает набор их прямых
> родительских объектов. Также можно
> использовать выражение (селектор), чтобы
> дополнительно отфильтровать набор
> элементов. Если ни одного
> родительского объекта не было найдено,
> то возвращается объект jQuery нулевой
> длины.

Решение:

```
var my1 = $("#my2").parent();
```